# Period of oscillation with time independent factor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

How can you determine the period of oscillation from a mass that is suspended from the ceiling? The equation becomes: ${{d^2x}\over dt^2}+kx-mg=0$. I am confused by the constant $mg$, because in the classical damped harmonic motion, the damping is velocity dependent.

Comment: $kx - mg = k(x - mg/k)$

Comment: There is no damping in a mass that is suspended from the ceiling, unless you take in account air resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually appears to be "ye olde harmonic oscillator" that has been shifted by a constant amount and not a [damped harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator) that you state it is.

To see the shifted behavior, let
$$
\eta(t)=x(t)-\frac{mg}{k}
$$
Direct substitution gives you
$$
\frac{d^2\eta}{dt^2}+k\eta=0\tag{1}
$$
where we used that $mg/k$ is constant for the time-derivative term. (1) is your standard harmonic oscillator.

Comment: This is very helpful.